# How does the new Backbone View 'events' hash work with function values instead of strings in version 0.9.0?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

The Backbone 0.9.0 changelog says:

> A view's events hash may now also contain direct function values as
>   well as the string names of existing view methods.

When I try the following it fails, saying that the value for the event is `undefined`.

```
var BB = Backbone.View.extend({
  'initialize': function() {

    this.$el.html('<input type="button" value="Click me!" />');
    jQuery('body').html(this.el);
  },

  'events': {
    'click input[type="button"]': this.buttonClicked
  },

  'buttonClicked': function() {
    alert('button clicked!');
  }

});

window.b = new BB()
```

Am I misunderstanding the new feature? Can somebody explain how it works differently than I expected?  Perhaps it's just my JavaScript syntax/value of 'this' at definition time that is borked.

The way I'm used to doing it still works:

```
'events': {
  'click input[type="button"]': 'buttonClicked'
},
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the JavaScript parser gets here:

```
'events': {
  'click input[type="button"]': this.buttonClicked
},
```

`this` is probably `window`, not an instance of `BB` as you expect. The `window` object doesn't have a `buttonClicked` property (at least it doesn't in your case) so you're really saying this:

```
'events': {
  'click input[type="button"]': undefined
},
```

and there's your error.

If you look at the source for [`delegateEvents`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1063), you'll see what the ChangeLog means:

```
delegateEvents: function(events) {
  // ...
  for (var key in events) {
    var method = events[key];
    if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
    // ...
  }
},
```

That [`_.isFunction`](http://underscorejs.org/#isFunction) call is what you're interested in. That means that you can say things like this:

```
events: {
  'click input[type="button"]': function() { alert('pancakes!') },
  'click button': some_function_that_is_in_scope
}
```

So you can put defined functions (either by their name if they're accessible or as function literals) in the `events` lookup table.

Comment: Very good, thank you.  The only thing I wonder at this point is whether each anonymous function I defined (such as the 'pancakes!' one in your example) will have its value of 'this' scoped to the view, or if it will be whatever the target of the event is.  It seems to me that this line would ensure it is scoped to the View itself:  method = _.bind(method, this);

Comment: @awcrud: Line 1078 (and this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JEavM/1/) indicate that the anonymous function will be scoped to the view.